# How to make every subsequent sibling after a button-wrapper disappear and restore their visibility again by pressing this very button?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, event-handling, dom-events

I have 2 buttons on a page, "read more" and a "read less", which are created using a Page Builder in WP. I am trying to hide all elements after the Read More button when the page loads. Once the button is clicked I want the "Read More" to display: none; and then every element that was hidden after the "Read More" button to be visible and then that button be hidden while the "Read Less" button is then visible and vice versa.

So far I have this code which will display the parent and then all siblings excluding the element that I want as the starting point. I've watched a bunch of videos and I am sure there's an easier way to achieve this but it has to be done this certain way.

```js
const readMore = document.getElementById("read-more");
const readLess = document.getElementById("read-less");

var getSiblings = function(elem) {

  // Setup siblings array and get the parent
  var siblings = [];
  var sibling = elem.parentNode.firstChild;

  // Loop through each sibling and push to the array
  while (sibling) {
    if (sibling.nodeType === 1 && sibling !== elem) {
      siblings.push(sibling);
    }
    sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
  }

  return siblings;
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.
  </div>
  <div class=".et_pb_button_0_wrapper">
    <button>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" id="read-more">READ MORE</a>
        </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.
  </div>

  <div>
    <button>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" id="read-less">READ LESS</a>
        </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you provide the html?

Comment: `I am sure there's an easier way to achieve this but it has to be done this certain way.` - then what is the question? If it HAS to be done this certain way, then you've achieved it

Comment: @terpinmd unfortunately I can't BUT let me see if I can whip something up that's similar to share.

Comment: @jaromanda The question is.. How can I add functionality to the buttons/page where it makes sense. When the page loads I need every element after the READ MORE button to have display: none; Once the user clicks the READ MORE btn - that will then display none but I need every element that was hidden to display including a READ LESS button and then once the READ LESS button gets click I need everything to be hidden up to where the READ MORE button is being displayed.

Comment: Please put all information in your question. There's no need for lengthy explanations in comments if you've written a good question.

Comment: FYI, an anchor element has no business inside a button element. They have different purposes and combining them is invalid HTML.

Comment: Ahh, so you have two const and a function but don't use any of them - I see

Comment: Is there CSS that goes with this?

Comment: @rnkwill ... Regarding the so far provided answers / solutions, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no need for a link placed inside a button.

Second, one does not even have to give the `<div/>` wrapper around the *"READ MORE"* button a class-name.

One can achieve what the OP is looking for with a minimum effort solution which does not involve any class-name but which ...

- **a)** makes use mainly of the [functional `:has()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) and the [*Subsequent-sibling combinator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator)
- **b)** does in addition register an event-handler at each of both buttons where both handlers take care of just the *"READ MORE"* related [button-element's `disabled` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement/disabled)/state.

The implementation then comes with a footprint as small as follows ...

```js
document
  .querySelector('#read-more')
  .addEventListener('click', ({ currentTarget: elmReadMore }) =>

    elmReadMore.disabled = true
  );

document
  .querySelector('#read-less')
  .addEventListener('click', () =>

    document.querySelector('#read-more').disabled = false
  );
```

```css
div:has(#read-more:disabled),
div:has(#read-more:not(:disabled)) ~ * {
  display: none;
}
button[id] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* text-transform: capitalize; */
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</div>
<!-- <div class="et_pb_button_0_wrapper"> -->
<div>
  <button id="read-more">Read more</button>
</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</div>
<div>
  <button id="read-less">Read less</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A sprinkling of CSS here, alongside your JS, will do wonders:

```
.read-more.activated,
.read-more:not(.activated) ~ :is(p, button) {
  display: none;
}
```

This snippet declares that:

- when the `.read-more` button has the `.activated` class it will not display
- when the `.read-more` button does *not* have the `.activated` class, all `<p>` or `<button>` elements which follow it (as subsequent siblings) will not display

Then, all your JavaScript needs to deliver is:

1. when the `.read-more` button is clicked, the `.activated` class is added to the `.read-more` button; and
2. when the `.read-less` button is clicked, the `.activated` class is removed from the `.read-more` button.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const readMoreButton = document.querySelector('.read-more');
const readLessButton = document.querySelector('.read-less');

const activateReadMoreButton = () => {
  readMoreButton.classList.add('activated');
}

const deactivateReadMoreButton = () => {
  readMoreButton.classList.remove('activated');
}

readMoreButton.addEventListener('click', activateReadMoreButton);
readLessButton.addEventListener('click', deactivateReadMoreButton);
```

```css
.read-more.activated,
.read-more:not(.activated) ~ :is(p, button) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</p>
<button type="button" class="read-more">READ MORE</button>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, ex.</p>
<button type="button" class="read-less">READ LESS</button>
```